# How to create a drag and drop area to upload files like Gmail?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

In Gmail, while composing an email, if you drag a file to the compose area (editor) to attach a file, the compose area turns to a *drag and drop* area to upload files.

I would like to know how to do the following thing:

> How to turn an HTML element to a drag and drop file upload area, when
>   the user drags a file over the element?

It's not necessary to turn the element to drag and drop file upload area. But there can be another HTML element, which works as a drag and drop file upload area and this needs to appear on the top of first element, when user drags the file over first element. So, I need to know how to know when user drags a file and move it over any html element. This is like `mouseover` event with a dragged file. What is this event?

Answer (score 4):

There is a jQuery plugin that allow you to drag & drop files to be uploaded... Look for [jQuery File Upload Demo](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

To do what you want, you have to add `mouseIn` event handling, and in the event, do this :

```
function draggingIn(e) {

   var count =  e.dataTransfer.files.length; (like Chamika Sandamal function)

   if (count > 0) {
        //A file is dragged
        $('droppable').addClass('showBox');
   }
}
```

For recent browsers, you can use HTML5 draggable capability [see here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html)

It looks like this : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUGBV/10/) I made some tests, just look for drag events

Comment: This seems to be a nice File Upload plugin and it works similar to my requirement. I will try this plugin and will find more about my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I use it as soon as I need to upload files... It's a great plugin, easy to configure and to adapt...

Comment: Currently I am using plupload for a project. I am specifying an element to drag and drop files to upload as shown in this image: http://d.pr/i/5Rgm . I am looking for a solution, so that this drag and drop area will appear, when the user drags the files to the browser.

Comment: You just need to trigger mouseIn and mouseOut event... [jQuery mouseOut mouseIn](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)  Or do you want the drag&drop area just appear if a file is dragging?

Comment: No mouseIn and mouseOut events. I don't that to appear, if the user moves the mouse over it. I want that to appear, only if the user is dragging a file to the browser (as your said in the second sentence).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something by yourself, maybe google for it? [sample at html5demos.com](http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload)

Comment: This plugin is good, but there is an element to drag and drop, which is already specified. I want this to appear, when user drags a file over a different element. However, I will try this plugin and few more plugins and let you know when I will find what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Refere this site because Gmail drag and drop is done in this concept.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop

If you have any queries you can post below